# Can UNION and WITH play together?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there any way to use the results of a UNION in another sub-query using a WITH clause?

I'm looking for something like

```
(
  MATCH (me:Person)-[:RATES]->(r:Rating)-[:RATED_BY]->(them:Person)
  WHERE me.ident = {id} AND r.date = {date}
  RETURN them
  UNION ALL
  MATCH (me:Person)<-[:RATED_BY]-(r:Rating)<-[:RATES]-(them:Person)
  WHERE me.edent = {id} AND r.date = {date}
  RETURN them
)
WITH them
RETURN them.name, COUNT( them.name) as ratingCount
ORDER BY ratingCount DESC
LIMIT 10
```

only nothing like this is supported by cypher.

And yes, I know that in this case I should be using

```
MATCH (me:Person)-[:RATES|RATED_BY]-(r:Rating)-[:RATES|RATED_BY]-(them:Person)
WHERE me.ident = {id} AND r.date = {date}
RETURN  them.name, COUNT( them.name) as ratingCount
ORDER BY ratingCount DESC
LIMIT 10
```

which is fine and dandy, but I think that I'm going to get some more complex requests down the road where this won't work.

Comment: Can you put in the question you have tried with?

Comment: Is the example in the question what you're looking for?

Comment: Certainly somewhere on the roadmap. For now you can limit both returns and order them too so you get at most 20 results and you can quickly resort and limit them in the client.

Comment: Actually your suggestion doesn't work: For example, if I have the sets (A:5, B:5, C:4) and (D:5, E:5, C:4), then a limit of 2 should give (C:8, A:5) but your solution would give something like (A:5, B:5). But that's OK. I'm going with the alternative relationship names for the moment.

Comment: Running into this too. And agreed, ordering & limiting the sub-queries before returning them doesn't get you the right ordering & de-duplication *across* the sub-queries.